# ValueError when running simple asyncio script

Tags: python-asyncio

I'm learning about asycio and trying to run this script I get this error:

> ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got <async_generator object
> mygen at 0x7fa2af959a60>

What am I missing here?

```
import asyncio

async def mygen(u=10):
     """Yield powers of 2."""
     i = 0
     while i < int(u):
         yield 2 ** i
         i += 1
         await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

asyncio.run(mygen(5))
```

Comment: Your problem is the use of `yield`. You need to iterate over the generator with `async for`. `asyncio.run` won’t do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [asyncio.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) function expects a [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-coroutine) but `mygen` is an [asynchronous generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-asynchronous-generator).

You can try something like this:

**test.py:**

```
import asyncio


async def mygen(u=10):
    """Yield powers of 2."""
    i = 0
    while i < int(u):
        yield 2**i
        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


async def main():
    async for i in mygen(5):
        print(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py 
1
2
4
8
16
```

**References:**

- [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/1416672)
- [PEP 525 -- Asynchronous Generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/)

Comment: Can you provide any input on this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71169287/asyncio-and-paramiko-for-concurrent-ssh-connectivity