# asyncio and paramiko for concurrent ssh connectivity

Tags: ssh, python-asyncio, paramiko

I'm trying to speed up the Paramiko SSH connection to a couple of network devices. I want to use asyncio for that purpose, but I'm not sure if my implementation of it is correct, as I don't see any benefit in execution time, with our without using it, the scripts executes for around 6s each time. The idea was, for he second host to start the its SSH connection without waiting for the SSH connection of the first host to be established.

Here is my current code, which runs but doesn't produce any benefit. Any suggestion how to make it work or improve, if that is possible here.

```
import paramiko
import time
import asyncio

async def sshTest(ipaddress,deviceUsername,devicePassword,sshPort): #finalDict
    try:
            print("Performing SSH Connection to the device")
            client = paramiko.SSHClient()
            client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            client.connect(ipaddress, username=deviceUsername, password=devicePassword, port=sshPort, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
            print("Channel established")         
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)       

async def main():
    print("Session 1 \n")
    await sshTest('192.168.255.11','admin','admin','22')
    print("Session 2 \n")
    await sshTest('192.168.254.11','admin','admin','22')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    asyncio.run(main())
    end = time.time()
    print("The time of execution of above program is :", end-start)
```

Comment: Adding just the `async` keyword won't make a function asynchronous, take a look at [AsyncSSH](https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute this task asynchronously, create a task list and add each asyncio task to that list. With `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` your function executes the task asynchronously with an I/O binding.

**EDIT**
With respect to the comment from @satman I added a `asyncssh` function instead of `paramiko`

```
#import paramiko
import asyncssh
import time
import asyncio

async def sshTest(ipaddress,deviceUsername,devicePassword,sshPort): #finalDict
    try:
            print("Performing SSH Connection to the device")
            #client = paramiko.SSHClient()
            #client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            #client.connect(ipaddress, username=deviceUsername, password=devicePassword, port=sshPort, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
            async with  asyncssh.connect(ipaddress, username=deviceUsername, password=devicePassword, known_hosts=None) as conn:
              async with conn.start_sftp_client() as sftp:
                #Here you can enter the commands you want to execute, e.g. import data from a device
                await sftp.get("folder_device", "folder_local", preserve=True, recurse=True)


            print("Channel established")      
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)       


async def main():
    start = time.time()

    ip_list = ['192.168.254.11','192.168.255.11']
    tasks = []
    for ip in ip_list:
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(sshTest(ip,'admin','admin','22')))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    end = time.time()
    print("The time of execution of above program is :", end-start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you actually use paramiko asynchronously as is suggested above. There in only one thread and if paramiko blocks, it will not transfer control to the other task, i think. The library also needs to be designed asynchronously, no? So if you want asynchronous ssh-connections, you have to use asyncssh.